# Applet pede método main ao executar, mas não possui este método

Tags: java, método

Empacotei o mu projeto em um jar que é uma applet e quero que essa applet rode aqui no linux navegador antigo do firefox, porém, pede pra selecionar um método main, mas o Applet não tem método main. Como fazer ele executar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
package xxx;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;
//import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class TesteApplet extends Applet {

    public String conteudo = "";
    public String formulario;
    public String campo;
    //public JSObject campoDoFormularioHTML; 
//
    public void init() {
          formulario = getParameter("formulario");
          campo = getParameter("campo"); 

          ActionListener trataEventos = new ActionListener(){


           public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
           conteudo += e.getActionCommand();
          // campoDoFormularioHTML.setMember("value", "" + conteudo);
           }

       };

       Button b7 = new Button("7");
       this.add(b7);
       b7.addActionListener(trataEventos);

       System.out.println();

       Button b8 = new Button("8");
       this.add(b8);
       b8.addActionListener(trataEventos);

       Button b9 = new Button("9");
       this.add(b9);
       b9.addActionListener(trataEventos);

       Button b4 = new Button("4");
       this.add(b4);
       b4.addActionListener(trataEventos);

       Button b5 = new Button("5");
       this.add(b5);
       b5.addActionListener(trataEventos);

       Button b6 = new Button("6");
       this.add(b6);
       b6.addActionListener(trataEventos);


       Button b1 = new Button("1");
       this.add(b1);
       b1.addActionListener(trataEventos);

       Button b2 = new Button("2");
       this.add(b2);
       b2.addActionListener(trataEventos);

       Button b3 = new Button("3");
       add(b3);
       b3.addActionListener(trataEventos);

       Button b0 = new Button("0");
       this.add(b0);
       b0.addActionListener(trataEventos);

       Button limpa = new Button("Limpa");
       this.add(limpa);
       limpa = new Button();
          // limpa.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    //      
//      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
//          conteudo = "";
//          campoDoFormularioHTML.setMember("VALUE", conteudo);
//      }
//     });
//              
//     JSObject objWin = JSObject.getWindow(this);
//     JSObject objDoc = (JSObject) objWin.getMember("document");
//     JSObject objForms = (JSObject) objDoc.getMember("forms");
//     JSObject objForm = (JSObject) objForms.getMember("formulario");
//     JSObject  objElements = (JSObject) objForms.getMember("elements");
//     campoDoFormularioHTML = (JSObject) objElements.getMember(campo);
//     campoDoFormularioHTML.setMember("value", ""); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se as edições que eu fiz não modificaram sua intenção na pergunta, acredito que assim, ela fica mais objetiva. E veja se seu Applet possui um método `init()`, que seria o equivalente ao método `main`.

Comment: sim, possui. Mas eu quero uma solução só isso.

Comment: Entendo, mas você está passando informações muito superficiais para que possamos ajudar. Lembre-se que não sabemos como funciona e nem como foi codificado sua aplicação. Veja se o jar possui arquivo manifest, e se nele está apontado para a classe do seu Applet que possui esse método `init()`

Comment: manifest? O que eu coloco nele e onde coloco ele?

Comment: Você está tentando executar applet por onde? Direto do browser ou via terminal do linux? Se for via terminal, que comandos está usando?

Comment: boa pergunta ainda não cheguei nessa parte...mas direto no navegador mesmo

Comment: Sua classe está estendendo de `java.applet.Applet`? seria interessante adicioná-la pra gente poder ver se é um erro no código.